# Simply find point in circle border

Tags: circles, angle, spectral-radius

This seems to silly for you expert guys in math but I am not good in this So Please help.

Suppose you have clock  of 330 * 330 pixels so    I have radius 165 in circle.

I want to find  position of  **1** (in clock ) . so circle is 360 degrees

so 360 / 12 = 30 Degree per hour

To find 1'O Clock position I have tried

**x = cos(30) * 165**  which is 25.4514892315. how to use this value.

Any Help would be appreciated

[image]

What I need is  Put White circle at 1 O Clock position  White circle size is 20 Pixel Orange circle size is 330 Pixel

[image]

Comment: You are correct to look at $30^\circ$ and the trig functions.  If the center of the circle were $(0,0)$ and up corresponded to a positive $y$ direction then the point you are interested in would be $(165\sin(30^\circ),165\cos(30^\circ))$.  Since your center is probably not called $(0,0)$ however, you will likely need to translate (*or even reflect*) the result further.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for comment. As i didn't know math terms well can you explain in simple lang ? because sin(30) * 165  is -163.025217975. Not able to place it properly

Comment: Assuming center is $(0,0)$ the point you want is $(165\sin(30^\circ),165\cos(30^\circ))\approxeq (82.5, 143)$.  As an aside, you want $165\cos(30^\circ)\approx 143$ where $30^\circ$ is a measurement of angle in *degrees*.  You apparently forgot to set your calculator to degrees mode.  With the calculator in radians mode instead you get $165\cos(30~\text{rad})\approx 25.45$ which is not what you want.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks  Yes you are correct I was not using degree mode cal. I am able to get (82.5, 143). But I need to convert his to coordinates. any help. Now My circle centre = 165 , 165 so I need to put white view according to  165,165 ? with value I got 82 and 143

Comment: Add 165 to both numbers

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks Solved it.